# How to correctly manipulate asychronous code in vue 3

Tags: async-await, vuejs3

I probably have a beginners question regarding asynchronous code and its correct use.

I a single Vue3 template (composition API) I do the following (code below):

1. Asynchronously fetch from json-server a list of quotes and store in a ref. (works fine)
2. extract taglist (array in quote object) from quotes object (works fine)
3. output it in the template (this works fine)

Now I would like to introduce an input field, where I can a) type letters that b) will filter the quotes and update the output of the quotes in the template.

I am aware that the code in the function matching quotes probably runs first (because the async task is performed later) and I tried to resolve this through the computed dunction (as it should only get triggered once the input field is changed), but this is not working.

Error message in the console is: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: quote.includes is not a function"

How would you do that correcty.

1. get data from fetch --> display in template
2. whenever there is an input in the input field: filter the list of quotes and putput it in the template again.

Thans much in advance,
Tim

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="search">
        <p>search term - {{ search }}</p>
        <div v-for="name in quotes" :key="name">{{ name }}</div>
        <div v-for="name in matchingQuotes" :key="name">{{ name }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    setup() {

        const search = ref('')

        const quotes = ref([])
        const tags = ref([])
        const tagSet = new Set()

        const load = async () => {

            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/quotes')
            let rawData = await response.json()
            quotes.value = rawData

            rawData.forEach(quoteObject => {
                quoteObject.tags.forEach(tag => tagSet.add(tag))
            });
            tags.value = [...tagSet]
        }
        load()
        const matchingQuotes = computed(() => {
            return quotes.value.filter(quote => quote.includes(search.value))
        })

        return {
            quotes,
            search,
            matchingQuotes
        }

    },

}
</script>
```

1. Did it without an asynchronous code block --> just a simple array: did work

Answer (score 0):

I would check what is wrong with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: quote.includes is not a function`. Most important words are `quote.includes is not a function`. I would question my self why it is not a function? Well, then I would check, oh I'm assigning to it some `ref([])`. Well, what that function is assigning to my `quote` variable. Oh, it's a generic object, then I would google "Vue 3 how to read Ref data". And I would know that I first need to get `.value` of it, then I have access to my array.

Oh, and don't use computed to search data. Use simple function and add button to trigger function when you write text in input.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. It pointed in the right direction. The following code did make the trick :-)

```
const keyUpHandler = () => { 
let filteredQuotes = quotes.value 
.filter(quote => quote.tags 
.some(tag => tag.includes(search.value))) 
matchingQuotes.value = filteredQuotes
```